# Trouble writing HTML in Razor view if/else condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm not quite sure what I am missing here, but I am having trouble adding a `class='success'` to a `<tr>` in a Partial View while iterating through a list in my Model.

My goal is to have the first row's `tr` to have the attribute `class='success'`

Here is the code I have:

```
@model List<DxRow>

<div class="row">
    <table class="table" id="diagnosis">
        <tr id="header-row">
            <th>Dx Code</th>
            <th>Dx Description</th>
            <th>Dx Date</th>
            <th>OnSet Or Ex</th>
            <th>Dx Order (Top is Primary)</th>
        </tr>

    @{ bool IsFirst = true; }
    @foreach (DxRow r in Model)
    {
           if (IsFirst)
           { 
               Html.Raw("<tr class='success'>");
               IsFirst = false;
           }
           else
           {
               Html.Raw("<tr>");
           }
       <tr>

        <td>@r.dxCode</td>
        <td>@r.dxDescription</td>
        <td>@r.dxDate</td>
        <td>@r.dxType</td>
        <td>
            <span class='up'><i class='icon-arrow-up bigger-160' style='color:green'></i></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class='down'><i class='icon-arrow-down bigger-160' style='color:red'></i></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class='top'><i class='icon-star bigger-160' style='color:goldenrod'></i></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class='delete'><i class='icon-trash bigger-160' style='color:red'></i></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

When I step through the code, it goes into the special `IsFirst` section the first iteration and the `else` section on all other iterations.

But, when I use FireBug to view the source code, it is not writing the part: `<tr class='success'>` , just the `<tr>`.

Comment: Could the problem be the extra `<tr>` right after your `if...else` block?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker.  I think I need to re-write this question.  I put that there to get the view to work.  If I remove that `<tr>`, the Razor view cannot figure out that I am conditionally writing the `<tr>` element, and gives me errors about no matching `<tr>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the extra `<tr>` after your `if` statement might be causing the browser to ignore your html, as the html would actually be broken with two `<tr>` tags being rendered.

I would probably update the code to be more like;

```
@{ bool IsFirst = true; }
@foreach (DxRow r in Model)
{

   <tr class="@( IsFirst ? "success" : "")">

       <td>@r.dxCode</td>
       <td>@r.dxDescription</td>
       <td>@r.dxDate</td>
       <td>@r.dxType</td>
       <td>
           <span class='up'><i class='icon-arrow-up bigger-160' style='color:green'></i></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class='down'><i class='icon-arrow-down bigger-160' style='color:red'></i></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class='top'><i class='icon-star bigger-160' style='color:goldenrod'></i></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class='delete'><i class='icon-trash bigger-160' style='color:red'></i></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    IsFirst = false;

}
```

Since you are setting `IsFalse` to false after the first loop. Makes the code tidier.

Comment: Thanks @TimBJames!  That's what I was looking for.  The way I was trying caused errors because it couldn't find a matching `<tr>`.  That's why I put in the extra `<tr>`, but forgot to take it out.

Comment: You maybe also want to consider just using CSS for this. In css these is a `first-child` selector. So you can target the first Row of your table. Take a look at this little example here [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qokakodu/1/edit)